# Draw a rectangle over an object using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, image-segmentation

I have an image which contains a coin image. Shape of the coin may be rectangle, square, circle, oval and etc. I want to draw a rectangle over the coin and segment the coin from it's background. I can't give x or y values of the rectangle, since coin may be in anywhere in the image. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is it a binary image? i.e., ones where the coin is and zeros elsewhere? or can it be converted to one?

Comment: @R. M. original one is a colored image and I have a binary version of that image also.

Comment: When you say you want to draw a rectangle over the coin, does that mean that you wish to select a small region containing the coin and then do the segmentation on this smaller image?

Answer (score 1):

My answer below assumes that you have already identified the coin and you have a cleaned image (binary would be nice) that you can work with.

```
coin=load('penny.mat'); %#load matlab's stock image
img=zeros(256,256);
img(65:192,65:192)=coin.P;%# this is an approximation to the sort of image that I think you have
```

[image]

Now we need the extents of the image in order to know the size of the bounding rectangle. Since the array is non-zero where there's an image and zero elsewhere, the following gives the length of the sides.

```
sideX=sum(sum(img,1)>0);
sideY=sum(sum(img,2)>0);
```

Find the centroid of the image using `kmeans`.

```
[indX,indY]=ind2sub(size(img),find(img(:)>0));
[~,centroid]=kmeans([indX,indY],1);
```

Now finally overlay the rectangle on top of the image.

```
imagesc(img);colormap(gray);hold on
rectangle('Position',([centroid,sideX,sideY]-[sideX,sideY,0,0]/2),'EdgeColor','w');hold off
```

Result:

[image]

If you have a noisy image (i.e., it's not uniformly zero outside the image, then you'd have to set a threshold to find the bounding box)

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the MathWorks [advice on pattern recognition](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18VZT/index.html).  Exactly how you solve the problem depends on many things, for example

- what else is in the image apart from a coin?
- are all the coins the same colour or different colours?
- do you have a training set of images that with identified coin locations?